# React firestoreConnect limit update frequency

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to limit frequency of updates from Firestore in React in a firestoreConnect component.

I'd like it to limit to say update only once in 10 seconds. Tried to search a lot but couldn't find anything of much relevance.

Thanks in advance :)